# Fill object from text file c++

Tags: c++, class, object, vector, file-io

I am writing a program which requires loading a database from a text file. The database class contains a vector of entries and the entries are a class.

example

```
vector<People> lib;
```

```
class People {
 string name;
 string occupation;
 int cats_age[2]
 int age;
//code here
}
```

How do I fill the database from a text file that contains entries formatted

```
marry wang-dog walker-0-17-78
```

I have tried using

```
file.read((char*)& entry, sizeof(entry))
```

but it has not worked

I have also considered overloading the operator >> however some fields are strings which contain spaces. 
How do I fill the object by reading in everything in between the character "-"?

-Thanks

Comment: Unrelated: The name `People` isn't good since it's actually only containing one Person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do a raw `read` from a file into a `People` object. `People` contains a non-trivial type (`std::string`) and each record in the file would have to have the same size for raw reads to work, which isn't the case in your file.

What people often do is to add an overload for `operator>>` to support formatted input from any `std::istream` (like a `std::ifstream` or `std::cin`).

Since the member variables are `private` you need to make the added `operator>>` a `friend` so it can access the `private` variables.

You can use `std::getline` to read until a certain character is found (like your delimiter `-`). It'll remove the delimiter from the stream but not include it in the variable it's storing the result in.

`std::getline` returns a reference to the `istream` it was given to read from so you can chain multiple `std::getline`s.

I'd also rename your class to `Person` since it's only containing info about one person.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <sstream>

class Person {
    std::string name;
    std::string occupation;
    int cats_age[2];
    int age;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Person&);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Person&);
};

// read one Person from an istream
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Person& p) {
    using std::getline;
    char del; // for reading the delimiter '-'
    std::string nl_eater; // for removing the newline after age

    // chaining getline:s and >>:s
    return getline(getline(getline(is, p.name, '-'), p.occupation, '-') >>
                       p.cats_age[0] >> del >> p.cats_age[1] >> del >> p.age, nl_eater);
}

// write one Person to an ostream
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Person& p) {
    return os << p.name << '-' << p.occupation << '-' << p.cats_age[0] << '-'
              << p.cats_age[1] << '-' << p.age << '\n';
}

int main() {
    // example of an istream - it could just as well had been a std::ifstream
    std::istringstream is(
        "marry wang-dog walker-0-17-78\n"
        "foo bar-unemployed-1-2-3\n"
    );

    std::vector<Person> people;

    Person temp;
    while(is >> temp) { // loop for as long as extraction of one Person succeeds
        people.push_back(temp);
    }

    // print all the collected Persons
    for(const Person& p : people) {
        std::cout << p;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
marry wang-dog walker-0-17-78
foo bar-unemployed-1-2-3
```

I suggest that you choose a different field delimiter than `-` though. Many names contain `-` and so does negative numbers. Use a character that's unlikely to be included in any of the fields.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: As always, I am tempted to give my typical answer using ````std::regex````. But because your answer is very good and efficient, I save the work and simply UV your answer. +1